# Remove next substring from charter on last position in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have Excel sheet which contains data similar to

**Addresses**
xyz,abc,olk
opn,opk,prt
we-ylj,tyf,uyfas
oiui,ytfy,tydry - We also work in bla,bla,bla
ytfyt,tyfyt,ghfyt
i-hgsd,gsdf-hgd,sdgh,- We also work in xxx,yy,zzz
ytsfgh,gfasdg,tydsfyt

I want to remove all substring which is next to the character "**-**" only if it's in the last position.
Result should be like

xyz,abc,olk
opn,opk,prt
we-ylj,tyf,uyfas
oiui,ytfy,tydry
ytfyt,tyfyt,ghfyt i-hgsd,gsdf-hgd,sdgh
ytsfgh,gfasdg,tydsfyt

I tried with =Substitute function but unable to replace data because of the last substring separated from "-" is not similar.

Comment: I think this is going to be really ugly in Excel, given that you are dealing with unnormalized CSV data.  Is there any chance you could import your data with each CSV term on a separate row?

Comment: @jery i want remove all characters if cell value contains "-"  after last "," of a string

Comment: @Jerry I want to replace " " if cell contains - on last posion.

Comment: And what should be the result if the original text is `ytfyt,tyfyt,ghfyt i-hgsd,gsdf-hgd,sdgh`?

Comment: @Jerry if text is ytfyt,tyfyt,ghfyt i-hgsd,gsdf-hgd,sdgh  then no changes required. and result should be as it is

Comment: How Can I substitute all characters with " "  which are next to " - We". I tried with  =SUBSTITUTE(A2,"- We ",""). but unable to substitute all chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your specifications, I would use two columns just so it's not a very long formula:

In B1:

```
=IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))-1,LEN(A1))
```

This gets the position of the last `-` or the full text length.

Then in C1:

```
=LEFT(A1,IF(FIND(",",A1)<B1,B1,LEN(A1)))
```

This checks if there's a `,` before the last `-`. If there is no `,`, then the full text is taken.

[image]

---

EDIT: I only now noticed your edited comment. If it's just everything after `- We`, then I would use this:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND("- We",A1)-2,LEN(A1))))
```

Comment: Note that if you change A5: `ytfyt,tyfyt,ghfyt i-hgsd,gsdf-hgd,sdgh` your formula will return `ytfyt,tyfyt,ghfyt i-hgsd,gsdf`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're right. OP has changed the comment and I didn't notice it till now :(